# Multithreading Issue with group chat in Java Sockets

Tags: java, multithreading, server, client, socks

I have found a few instances of my problem but I cannot seem to fix it unfortunately after many hours. I basically have a Socket group chat application which allows clients to login, the server uses a database to check the login and then either allows the Client to move to the chat page or not. Once logged in, a Connect button is pressed to initialise the socket connection for the chat. I had got to the stage where I could have multiple clients and each could send a message, it would be taken by the server and sent to all clients but it could only be read by other clients if the send button was clicked. I have since tried many methods of getting it to work synchronised but now am back to a point where the server will not echo the messages back.

I would like advice on how to change the server to get the messages received from the clients and echo them back to all clients.

P.S. This is my first post, thank you in advance.

Server & Handler Code ----------------------

```
public class ServerHandler extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
static JTextField tfSend;
public static JTextArea textArea;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
static JButton btnSend;
private JButton btnSettings;




/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                ServerHandler frame = new ServerHandler();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

     // server is listening on port 8000 
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8000); 

      while (true)  
     { 
        Socket s = null; 

         try 
         { 
           //socket object to receive incoming client requests 
             s = ss.accept(); 
               textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\nA new client connected : " + s); 

              //obtaining input and out streams 

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); 
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream()); 
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            textArea.setText(textArea.getText() + "\nAssigning new thread for this client"); 


             // create a new thread object 
             ClientHandler t = new ClientHandler(s, ois, oos, dos,dis);                 
              //Invoking the start() method 
             t.start();                  

         } 
         catch (Exception e){ 
           s.close(); 
            ss.close();
             e.printStackTrace(); 
         } 
     } 
} 


public ServerHandler() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 700, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btnSend = new JButton("Send");
    btnSend.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    btnSend.setBounds(542, 404, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnSend);

    btnSettings = new JButton("Settings");
    btnSettings.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    btnSettings.setBounds(542, 30, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnSettings);

    tfSend = new JTextField();
    tfSend.setBounds(45, 404, 490, 26);
    contentPane.add(tfSend);
    tfSend.setColumns(10);
    tfSend.setEditable(false);


    textArea = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setLocation(47, 71);
    scrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    scrollPane.setSize(612,322);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
    textArea.setEditable(false);


    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(26, 23, 652, 429);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);
}  
}
class ClientHandler extends Thread  { 
    //thread conns
    private ObjectInputStream ois; 
    private ObjectOutputStream oos; 
    private DataOutputStream dos;
    private DataInputStream dis;
    private Socket s;

    //database conns
    static Connection c;
    static Statement stmt;
    static Connection c1;
    static Statement stmt1;     
    static Connection c2;
    static Statement stmt2;


    public ClientHandler(Socket s, ObjectInputStream ois, ObjectOutputStream oos, DataOutputStream dos2,  DataInputStream dis2) {
        this.s = s;
        this.ois = ois;
        this.oos = oos;
        this.dos = dos2;
        this.dis = dis2;
    }


    @Override
    public void run()  
    {   
        try {
            System.out.println("running");
            checkUTF();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}


    public void checkUTF() throws IOException, SQLException {
        while(true) {
            String check = null;
            check = dis.readUTF();
            System.out.println("check");
            if (check!= null) {
                System.out.println("switching");
                try {       
                    switch(check) {
                    case "chat":
                        System.out.println("chatting");
                        chat();
                    case "Login":
                        try {
                            System.out.println("checking login");
                            checkLogin();
                        } catch (SQLException e1) {
                            e1.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }}finally { 
                        System.out.println("ending");
                        close();
                    }       
            }else {

            }
        }
    }

    public void chat() throws IOException {

        dos.writeUTF("chat");
        dos.flush();
        ServerHandler.tfSend.setEditable(true);

        while(s.isClosed()==false) {
            String check = null;
            check = dis.readUTF();

            if (check!= null) {
                if(check.equals("close")){
                    dos.writeUTF("close");
                    break;
                }else{
                    dos.writeUTF(check);
                }
            }
        }
        }



public void close() throws IOException {
    dos.close();
    dis.close();
    oos.close();
    ois.close();
    s.close();
}

public void checkLogin() throws SQLException {
    ClientStuff.LoginObject login = null;

        System.out.println("here");
        try {
            login = (LoginObject) ois.readObject();
            System.out.println(login.getName() + login.getPassword());
            String username = login.getName().trim();
            String password = login.getPassword().trim();

                if((checkLoginDetails(username,password))==true) {
                    closeDatabase();
                    String status = "Found";
                    dos.writeUTF(status);
                    dos.flush();
                    System.out.println("ending2");

                }else {
                    closeDatabase();
                    String status = "Not Found";
                    dos.writeUTF(status);
                    dos.flush();
                    System.out.println("ending3");
                    close();
                }                                                   
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}



public static boolean checkLoginDetails(String username, String password) throws SQLException {

    startDatabaseConnections();
    stmt2 = c2.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt2.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CLIENTINFO WHERE USERNAME = '"+username+"' AND PASSWORD = '"+password+"';");
    while ( rs.next() ) {            
        return true;
    }

    rs.close();
    return false;
}


public static void startDatabaseConnections() {

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ServerInfo");
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }

    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ClientConvo");
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        c2 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:ClientInfo");
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
        System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void closeDatabase() throws SQLException {
    c.close();
    c1.close();
    c2.close();
    System.out.println("Databases Closed");
}

}
```

Client Login Code --------------

```
 public class UserLogin extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * 
 */

static UserLogin frame;

private JPanel contentPane;
private static JTextField tfUsername;
private  static JTextField tfPassword;
static boolean yes = false;

static JButton btnNewUser = new JButton("New User");
static JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");

static Socket login = new Socket();
private static String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
static ObjectOutputStream oos;
static ObjectInputStream ois;
static DataOutputStream dos;
static DataInputStream dis;

static String status = null;


/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws UnknownHostException 
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                frame = new UserLogin();
                if(frame.isVisible()==false) {
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

}
public void foundUser(String status) {
    if (status.equals("Found")) {
    frame.setVisible(false);
    dispose();
    new UserChat().setVisible(true);
}else if(status.equals("Not Found")) {
    close();
    tfUsername.setText("Not Found");
    tfPassword.setText("Not Found");
}
}

public void close(){
    System.out.println("closing");
    try {
        login.close();
        dos.close();
        dis.close();
        oos.close();
        ois.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void connectServer() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("start stream setup");
    login = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 8000);
    }

public void setupStreams() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("start stream setup 2");
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(login.getOutputStream());      
    System.out.println("obj output stream setup");
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(login.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("obj input stream setup");
    dos = new DataOutputStream(login.getOutputStream()); 
    System.out.println("data output stream setup");
    dis = new DataInputStream(login.getInputStream());  
    System.out.println("data input stream setup");
}



/**
 * Create the frame.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public UserLogin() throws IOException {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 700, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btnNewUser.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    btnNewUser.setBounds(373, 294, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnNewUser);

    btnLogin.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    btnLogin.setBounds(373, 253, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnLogin);

    tfUsername = new JTextField();
    tfUsername.setBounds(255, 175, 235, 26);
    contentPane.add(tfUsername);
    tfUsername.setColumns(10);

    tfPassword = new JTextField();
    tfPassword.setColumns(10);
    tfPassword.setBounds(255, 213, 235, 26);
    contentPane.add(tfPassword);

    JLabel lblUsername = new JLabel("Username");
    lblUsername.setBounds(127, 180, 104, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblUsername);

    JLabel lblPassword = new JLabel("Password");
    lblPassword.setBounds(127, 218, 104, 16);
    contentPane.add(lblPassword);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(26, 23, 646, 429);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    btnNewUser.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    new UserReg().setVisible(true);
                }
            }
            );

    btnLogin.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    LoginObject userLogin = new LoginObject(tfUsername.getText(),tfPassword.getText());
                    System.out.println(userLogin.getName() + userLogin.getPassword());
                    try {
                        connectServer();
                        setupStreams();
                        dos.writeUTF("Login");
                        dos.flush();
                        System.out.println("login");
                        oos.writeObject(userLogin);
                        oos.flush();
                        System.out.println("userlogin");
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    String status = null;
                    try {
                        status = dis.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(status);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(status);
                    foundUser(status);
                    }
                }
            );
}}
```

Client Chat Code ---------

```
   public class UserChat extends JFrame {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JPanel contentPane;
private static  JTextField tfSend;
private static JTextArea textArea;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;
private static JButton btnSend;
private JButton btnSettings;
private JButton btnLogout;
private JButton btnGetChat;
String messageIn = "";      


private static Socket login = new Socket();
private static String serverIP = "127.0.0.1";
static ObjectOutputStream oos;
static ObjectInputStream ois;
static DataOutputStream dos;
static DataInputStream dis;

static String status = null;
private JButton btnConnect;



/**
 * Launch the application.
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            UserChat frame = new UserChat();
            if(frame.isVisible()==false) {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });

    System.out.println("mainnn");
    }

public static void connectServer() throws IOException {
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"start stream setup\n");
    login = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 8000);
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"start stream setup 2\n");
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(login.getOutputStream());      
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"obj output stream setup\n");
    ois = new ObjectInputStream(login.getInputStream());
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"obj input stream setup\n");
    dos = new DataOutputStream(login.getOutputStream()); 
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"data output stream setup\n");
    dis = new DataInputStream(login.getInputStream());  
    textArea.setText(textArea.getText()+"data input stream setup\n");
    }


public static void whileChatting() throws IOException {
    tfSend.setEditable(true);

            if(login.isClosed()==false) {
                btnSend.addActionListener(
                        new ActionListener(){
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                                String sendText = "Client - ";
                                sendText += tfSend.getText();
                                try {
                                    dos.writeUTF(sendText);
                                    dos.flush();

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                tfSend.setText("");
                            }
                        }
                        );

                Thread t = new MsgHandler(login, ois, oos, dis,dos, textArea); 

                t.start(); 
            }
}
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public UserChat() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 700, 500);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    btnSend = new JButton("Send");
    btnSend.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    btnSend.setBounds(542, 404, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnSend);

    btnConnect = new JButton("Connect");
    btnConnect.setBounds(165, 31, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnConnect);

    btnSettings = new JButton("Settings");
    btnSettings.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    btnSettings.setBounds(542, 30, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnSettings);

    btnLogout = new JButton("Logout");
    btnLogout.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    btnLogout.setBounds(37, 30, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnLogout);

    btnGetChat = new JButton("Get Chat");
    btnGetChat.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    btnGetChat.setBounds(417, 30, 117, 29);
    contentPane.add(btnGetChat);

    tfSend = new JTextField();
    tfSend.setBounds(45, 404, 490, 26);
    contentPane.add(tfSend);
    tfSend.setColumns(10);
    tfSend.setEditable(false);

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setLocation(47, 71);
    scrollPane.setAutoscrolls(true);
    scrollPane.setSize(612,322);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
    textArea.setEditable(false);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("");
    lblNewLabel.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED, null, null, null, null));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(26, 23, 652, 429);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    btnLogout.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    try {
                        dos.writeUTF("logout");
                        dos.flush();
                        System.out.println("Servers Closed");   
                        dispose();
                        setVisible(false);
                        UserLogin.main(null);
                    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }
            );
    btnConnect.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                        try {
                            connectServer();
                            dos.writeUTF("chat");
                            dos.flush();
                            String chat = dis.readUTF();
                            System.out.println(chat);
                                if(chat.equals("chat")) {
                                    System.out.println(chat);
                                    btnConnect.setVisible(false);
                                    whileChatting();
                                }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            System.out.println("Here");
                        }

                    }
                }
            );

    }
  }



 class MsgHandler extends Thread{
final ObjectInputStream ois; 
final ObjectOutputStream oos; 
final Socket s; 
DataOutputStream dos;
DataInputStream dis;
JTextArea textArea;

public MsgHandler(Socket s, ObjectInputStream ois, ObjectOutputStream oos, DataInputStream dis2, DataOutputStream dos2,
        JTextArea textArea){
    this.s = s; 
    this.ois = ois; 
    this.oos = oos; 
    this.dis = dis2; 
    this.dos = dos2; 
    this.textArea = textArea;
}

public void run(){

    try {
        checkUTF();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public void checkUTF() throws IOException  {
    System.out.println("running to listen");
    while(s.isClosed()==false) {
        String check = null;
        check = dis.readLine();
        if (check!= null) {
            if(check.equals("close")){
                close();
                break;
            }else{
                textArea.append("\n"+check);
                System.out.println("receive message from the server");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void close(){
    System.out.println("closing");
    try {
        s.close();
        dos.close();
        dis.close();
        oos.close();
        ois.close(); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `Please could someone help.`  Unfortunately: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Fair enough, I will edit the question to be more specific, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems in making chat servers using ports and sockets. To solve this problem, see if you have added all your code that starts up your socket and port reader in the button that sends messages from the client(in your case “btnSend”). The reason why this may affect the time a client receives a message is that you have to click the send button to activate the receiving end of the program. You can simply extract the parts of your code that start the thread and receive information from the button action listener. Hope this might help!